# Paging and double click with jQuery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-events

After lots of reading posts and fiddling, I thought this was working to attach a doubleclick 'handler' to each row of my jQuery datatable:

```
   $('#myTable').find('tr').dblclick( function(e){
        var ref = $(this).find('td:first').text();
        someThingToDoWithTextFromFirstCell(ref);
   });
```

Unfortunately, this only seems to work for rows on the first page.  I tried doing something like this as a workaround (basically do the same thing when paging):

```
   $('#myTable').on('page', function () {
       $('#myTable').find('tr').dblclick( function(e){
          var ref = $(this).find('td:first').text();
          someThingToDoWithTextFromFirstCell(ref);
       });
     } );
```

However, when it fires there are no tr's found so nothing happens.  I assume the event is firing before the datatable has new rows?

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Here is a JS Fiddle example, Nikola.  Thanks for your time.  Double click a row and get an alert, click next and double click a row and get no alert.
[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisrmead/9LTU7/)

This is what you can add in for the workaround that doesn't work:

```
 $('#example').on('page', function () {
   $('#example').find('tr').dblclick( function(e){
      var ref = $(this).find('td:first').text();
      alert(ref);
   });
 } );
```

Answer (score 3):

You could find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633789/jquery-on-with-doubleclick-event).

So, for dynamically created elements you should use:

```
$(document).on("dblclick", "#myTable tr", function () {
    //code here
});
```